# How to know what are the threads running : python

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there any way to know what threads are running using python threading module. With the following piece of code, I am able to get the Thread name, current thread, active thread count.

But my doubt here is ACTIVE_THREADS are 2 and the CURRENT THREAD is always "MainThread". What could be the other thread which is running at the back ground ?

```
import threading
import time

for _ in range(10):
    time.sleep(3)
    print("\n", threading.currentThread().getName())
    print("current thread", threading.current_thread())
    print("active threads ", threading.active_count())
```

---

### output of the above the code :

MainThread

current thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 11008)>

active threads  2

Comment: If the above code is your full program, it should show only a single thread, since it isn't launching any other ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access all current thread objects using [`threading.enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate), e.g.

```
for thread in threading.enumerate():
    print(thread.name)
```